# No Xamarin.Forms toolbar icons on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, icons, toolbar

I've created a Xamarin.Forms app with a tabbed page, containing 3 listviews.  The XAML in each listview page includes two toolbar icons.  These buttons display properly in Android, but no buttons are displayed in iOS.  Below is the code I'm using:

---

XAML on listview page

---

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HitDB;assembly=HitDB"
         x:Class="HitDB.Views.EmployeeListPage">
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Clicked="OnRefreshClicked" Text="R">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource" iOS="Refresh.png" Android="refresh.png" WinPhone="refresh.png" />
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem Clicked="OnSettingsClicked" Text="S">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource" iOS="Settings.png" Android="settings.png" WinPhone="settings.png" />
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

When the app starts, I display a login page.  If they login successfully, I display the home page:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
```

The HomePage contains the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HitDB
{
class HomePage : TabbedPage
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        Title = "HIT Dashboard";

        Children.Add(new Views.EmployeeListPage());
        Children.Add(new Views.OnCallListPage());
        Children.Add(new Views.AlertListPage());
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You are using a TabbedPage inside a NavigationPage why? It should be the other way around. If you need a NavigationPage you can create one on the TabbedPage childs that need it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

I originally tried that, but the text for the tabs didn't display.  It displays in the toolbar title, but not the tabs.